# Set location in request- php

Tags: php, http-headers, geolocation, user-agent

I am running an application which fetches data from amazon.ae. I use the code below.

```
<?php
    $link = 'https://www.amazon.ae/Huawei-P20-Pro-Dual-SIM/dp/B07MMQRNYT/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=huawei&qid=1557457063&s=electronics&sr=1-3';
    $opts = array(
        'http'=>array(
            'method'=>"GET",
            'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                  "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n" . 
                  "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36\r\n"
        // 'ignore_errors' => true
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $html = file_get_contents($link, false, $context);
    echo $html;
?>
```

My server is located in the USA. So the application opens the page as if it is browsing from the USA. This code displays the Amazon.ae page as below

[image: Opened from US]

The problem is - this is not how the page is displayed if a user opens the same URL from UAE. The page is displayed as below if opened from UAE.

[image]

You can see the 'price' and 'sold by' is different for both locations.

What I want to do is to fetch the page as if my application is running from UAE.
How do I make my application run the code from UAE instead of US.
Thanks in advance